# ORDER BY CASE not working with php GET

Tags: php, mysql

I'm showing a MYSQL database in a PHP page, ordered by the column "Seat".

I want that if a user clicks in the "Order By Name" link, the table now orders by this column.

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$resulted = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM guests ORDER BY case WHEN Seat = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, Seat");

if (isset($_GET['Name'])) {$resulted = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM guests ORDER BY case WHEN Name = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, Name");}
?>

<a href='?Name=true'>Order By Name</a>
```

When the user clicks the link, the table is indeed ordered by Name, but for some strange reasons, it ingores the ORDER BY CASE statment.

Why?

Comment: The SQL looks fine. Please provide sample data with which we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Like what? That's basically it.

Comment: can you show us where/how you're echoing any of this? did you check if your query failed too, or other parts of your code in regards to PHP?

Comment: I repeat: provide the data in the table, or a subset of it that demonstrates the problem. I cannot reproduce it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f20f/1 as you can see it orders according to the `case`.

Comment: You also need to assign a variable to that GET array and pass it in your query; that's most likely why you're not getting the resutls for it. All I see related to `Name` is your GET array's name and `WHEN Name = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, Name`.

Comment: if you know how to ping, then do. I've left the question, good luck.

Comment: Fred -ii- Take a look at the link, it sets the variable as true.

Comment: trincot On the SQL console it works great. In a PHP page it works great. The problem is when is in a PHP page inside a IF statment like the code i posted. The first ORDER BY in my code works fine, the second (inside if statement) doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure the `if` is working? Add something like `echo "Ordering by name";` to it.

Comment: the if is working. He does change the order, ordering by the Name column. But all the ' ' comes first, that is, it's ignoring the CASE.

Comment: I am voting to close. This problem needs (1) table structure with data types, (2) sample data (3) the code that displays the data (4) expected output, actual output, based on provided sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking `Seat = ''` try checking for `IS NULL` like

```
case WHEN Seat IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
```

(OR)

```
case WHEN Seat IS NULL OR Seat = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: problem is that the DEFAULT values of those columns are ' ' and not null.